# Personal Build, Remote Run, Pre-tested Commit with GIT and TeamCity

Tags: git, intellij-idea, teamcity

Is there an option to have pre-tested commit+push in IntelliJ + TeamCity with GIT similar to the way we have it in SVN?

From docs, it looks like it is not possible. is there a request for it or a workaround?

Comment: There is an extension for Visual Studio that does this, regardless of source control (if I remember correctly). Have you checked if there's something similar for IntelliJ?

Comment: Either way, you could commit to your own branch and push and have TeamCity build this. If it turns out you don't want that commit you can always force push to get rid of it (as long as you're on your own branch that is).

Answer (score 2):

Remote Run with git should be available, pre-tested commits not. Check the issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-11344, while it's pretty old, it has some discussion on possible alternatives that might work for your scenario.